# Alert dialog with text followed with a checkbox and 2 buttons

Tags: android

I have requirement to pop up alert dialog which is like a EULA screen.
Which will have text describing EULA with a checkbox "Don't show this again" and in the end 2 buttons for OK and Cancel.

How to have textview and checkbox as part of alert dialog?

Comment: An EULA never have a 'Don't show this again' kinda thing. Provide only Agree and Disagree button at the bottom. And put a link to your EULA in some menu in your program, so that users can view it any time they wish.

Comment: Also if this is not the best design solution for EULA, this can be needed for other dialogs that could optionally perform an further action.

Answer (score 16):

I have to agree with Mudassir, EULAs are not suppose to have "Don't show again" checkboxes, but here's how you could go about doing something like that though.

You can use a AlertDialog.Builder to build a dialog box that contains a view (which you can design in XML). Here's an example

```
AlertDialog.Builder eulaBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            LayoutInflater eulaInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View eulaLayout = eulaInflater.inflate(R.layout.eula, null);
            eulaBuilder.setView(eulaLayout);
            Checkbox dontShowAgain = (CheckBox)eulaLayout.findViewById(R.id.dontShowAgain);
            eulaBuilder.setPositiveButton("Agree", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int m) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });        
            eulaBuilder.setNegativeButton("Disagree", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int m) {
                    // Do something
                }
            });
            eulaMsg = eulaBuilder.create();
```

What you can do is create an XML with a single object, CheckBox. Then add the view into the AlertDialog.Builder. Use AlertDialog.Builder.setMessage("EULA message here") to set your EULA message.

Comment: I think this solution is missing one line eulaBuilder.setView(eulaLayout);

Answer (score 3):

Look at these two different method:

**1) First method more simply and very fast:**

```
CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(this);
checkBox.setText("This is your checkbox message");
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setLayoutParams( new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
linearLayout.setOrientation(1);     
linearLayout.addView(checkBox);

AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alertDialogBuilder.setView(linearLayout);
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("This is the title of alert dialog");
alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("This is the message of alert dialog");
alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
          // do something
     }
});
alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

**2) Second method, with a more customized layout:**

look this [page](http://misha.beshkin.lv/android-alertdialog-with-checkbox/), there is also the XML code to create the checkbox.

Comment: It has past a lot of time, but could you remember in the first method how would yo obtain the checkbox value inside the AlertDialog?

Comment: You can use the checkbox (previously marked as final) inside the "onClick". So, the "isChecked()" method is available and runs ok!. Thanks!