# Alert Dialog Box?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How do I put a checkbox in my dialog box where if the user doesn't check the box the positive button will not work and the negative button will close the dialog box.

Here is my code

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean agreed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed", false);
            if (!agreed) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setTitle("License agreement")
                        .setMessage("")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                                editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                                editor.commit();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .show();
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alert dialog with text follwed with a checkbox and 2 buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4965294/alert-dialog-with-text-follwed-with-a-checkbox-and-2-buttons)

Comment: Create a new Layout with checkbox and message then in `setPositiveButton` check if checkbox is checked or not. if checked then commit true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an rough work.

**Here is layout (about_us.xml).**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox_new"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="@string/creator_name"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Here is View Handler.**

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
boolean agreed = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("agreed", false);
if (!agreed) {
    View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about_us, null);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox_new);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
    alertBuilder.setView(view);
    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
             if (checkBox.isChecked()){
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                 editor.putBoolean("agreed", true);
                 editor.commit();
             }
         }
    });
    alertBuilder.create().show();
}
```

In this view handler i am checking if the checkbox is checked or not. if it is checked, commit true.

You can modify this code as you want.

Comment: Why are the buttons and the checkbox disappears when I put title and message

Comment: title and message does not work when setting custom view. so modify that layout in your way.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a custom `DialogFragment` with the layout of your choice and custom behavior like the disabled positive button.

Here are some tutorials:

- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html
- https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment